# Alternatives to FreeTDS?

Tags: c++, c, sql-server, linux, freetds

We're running a Linux server with Microsoft SQL Server for the database.  Are there any good (preferably open source) c libraries that we could use other than FreeTDS?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really. Sybase has some client libraries, but they only work for older versions of MS SQL Server (since it is a derivative of Sybase SQL Server).

Answer (score 0):

You can now try the [official closed source Microsoft SQL server ODBC drivers for linux](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568451%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I'd warn that I've had many issues with this driver. I've tried FreeTDS and this driver in several different environments. The main issues revolve around multithreading. The Microsoft driver does NOT handle multithreaded languages well. For example, in Django, you have to launch the runserver with the `--nothreading` option. There are also known issues with SQLRowCount returns, which will often cause errors in many ORMs. Just an FYI!